# Need to get updated value from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea in which I am inserting values selected from the autocomplete field, 
What I want to do is get the updated value from the textarea.

supposing I enter three characters a, b and c in the textarea
I delete character c. 
The problem I have is-> again when I select a character from the autocomplete field the character selected does not show up
in the textarea,

The character does get added to the memory i.e. the html code. But does not show up in the textarea. Below is the html

```
<div id="secondary" style="min-width:100px; min-height: 10px; float:left">write any character from a to f
    <br/>
    <label for="somechar"></label>
    <input id="somechar" size="22">
    <br>
    <textarea id="some-log" class="log" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery and javascript code

```
var secondary = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f"];
```

the function below logs the message in the textarea. here is where i need the updated value.
I dont know how i can use some thing like
`var thought= $("textarea#some-log").val();`  over here

```
function some_log(thought) {
    $("#some-log").append(thought+ ", ").prependTo("#some-log");
}

$("#somechar") /* this function is required when selecting multiple values */
.bind("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

This is Jquery autocomplete

```
    .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        secondary, extractLast(request.term)));
    },
    focus: function () {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        some_log(ui.item ? 
                          ui.item.value :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/MMpDv/

Comment: what is `extractLast`?

Comment: your jsfiddle has some problems, you need to select the jQuery framework and then also select jQuery UI as in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BR223/1/

Comment: I am using the autocomplete jquery ui code. here it wont matter. it doesnt have anything to do with the updating the text area field

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/MMpDv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function some_log(thought) {
    $("#some-log").val(function(){
        return this.value + thought + ',';
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z9ZPK/2/)